# How to migrate a workflow trigger in salesforce xml?

Tags: package, destructivechanges.xml, package.xml

how do I migrate a workflow trigger in the xml pacckage?
For example, I can migrate a workflow Rule, next way:

```
<types>
        <members>Opportunity.Update Opp Name</members>
        <name>WorkflowRule</name>
</types>
```

Thanks

Comment: The Example I gave wast complete because of thhhe xml tags.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a rule, you also want to create an action or field update. Those have separate components for you to add in the XML. They are listed as WorkflowFieldUpdate and WorkflowAction.